# JQuery / JavsScript mechanism to schedule methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to invoke a specific method at specific times. For example.

- after 10 seconds
- after 20 seconds
- after 35 seconds
- after 50 seconds
- after 60 seconds
- after 65 seconds

All times from the same starting point. I was looking at the JQuery Timer module but I don't think this will give it to me.

What is the a good approach to do this in JavaScript / Jquery? Or any plugin available from a CDN.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use functional programming :

```
var makeIntervals = function(timeList,callback){
 intervals = []
 for(i = 0; i< timeList.length ; i++ ){
  intervals.push(setTimeout(callback,timeList[i]))
 }
 return intervals
}
```

Comment: Why do you call this "functional programming"? Also, if you expect `timelist` to be an array, you should not use a for-in-loop.

Comment: Learn what higher order functions are. Also i dont see the problem using for-in-loop in my exemple, please explain the issue.

Comment: @camus why do you need the intervals array?  The for loop going around setTimeout() should do it.  What does the intervals array give you?

Comment: because you might want to clear the "timeouts" with `clearTimeout` function. setTimeout returns an id.

Comment: @camus See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays - also bear in mind that in cases when you can use a `for..in` loop, you should always use `hasOwnProperty` to ensure you're not getting a property from the object's prototype (`for(key in myObject) { if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) { ... } }`)

Answer (score 3):

This code will start timers for all the times you've suggested.

```
function funcToCall()
{
}

setTimeout(funcToCall, 10 * 1000 );
setTimeout(funcToCall, 20 * 1000 );
setTimeout(funcToCall, 35 * 1000 );
setTimeout(funcToCall, 50 * 1000 );
setTimeout(funcToCall, 60 * 1000 );
setTimeout(funcToCall, 65 * 1000 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout), and define your desired intervals in an array:

```
var method = function() { 
        console.log('did something'); 
    },
    intervals = [10, 20, 35, 50, 60, 65],
    i;

for (i = intervals.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    setTimeout(method, intervals[i] * 1000);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kelervin/Lg8P3/